# Разворачивание ASP.NET Core Web API на Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, ubuntu, asp.net-web-api, vds, asp-net-core-mvc

Всем привет!

Написал простенькое апи, хочу залить на VDS под управлением Ubuntu 16.04, установлен Apache сервер (Nginx установить не получится, не спрашивайте почему:) )

Пробовал следующее:
**ПКМ** по проекту -> **ОПУБЛИКОВАТЬ**, делал в локальную папку, далее заливал на VDS и уже на VDS, через **dotnet** запускал *.dll* файл:
**dotnet name.dll**

При таком раскладе апи запускалось, но локально

Может кто знает какие есть способы?

Comment: Docker? Вот только сегодня сам пробовал выгружать на нем проект.

Comment: Получилось? Можно ссылку на какую-нибудь статью?

Comment: Я вообще делал на Centos по этой статье https://1cloud.ru/help/linux/instruktsiya-docker-na-centos7 но там вроде без разницы какая ос. А так что у Вас именно не получается с докером? Я сегодня тоже целый день с ним боролся и в итоге поборол. Запустил 2 веб апи и 1 приложение на 1 впс.

Comment: Вообще не пробовал юзать докер, спасибо

Comment: Нифига не понял) возможно есть какой-то очень метод, который может всё сделать без докера? Пусть даже костыль, мне для личного использования

Comment: Ну я хз на счет костылей, докер самое легкое решение. Прямо в визуал студии нажали Опубликовать, выбрали докер, докерхаб. Залили. Затем на впс, загрузили образ, запустили. Все(ну или почти все=).

Comment: Даже звучит сложно)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thc4WYHcngk вот посмотрите видео, там все очень просто.

Comment: Воу, спасибо!!!

Comment: @User12351259599491, а получается, вот так через докер залил и готово? Не надо ничего больше запускать?

Comment: Да, на впс нужно будет установить только докер. Докер это как впс в впс)